# How to keep cream from separating in milk?

Tags: food

I have fallen in love with raw milk.  It tastes so much better than processed milk.  Raw milk is not pasteurized or homogenized.  Because the milk is not homogenized, the cream will separate from the milk.

I buy 3 quarts of milk at a time.  As I use the first quart, the cream is well mixed in the milk.  By the time I open the second and third quart, the cream has separated from the milk and settled at the top of the bottle.  How do I keep the cream from separating?  I suppose I could shake each quart each day, but that is more trouble than it is worth.

Comment: The Lifehacks site is about trying to solve life's unusual puzzles that need a bit of thinking outside the box. But this type of how-to question is better suited to our **[Cooking community](https://cooking.stackexchange.com)** who can handle these types of food-handling problems. Please feel free to re-ask your question in the context of *that* site. Good luck!

Comment: @RobertCartaino Thanks for the pointer.  I have created the question at https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/86424/how-to-keep-cream-from-separating-in-milk